# Angular (2) TREE . Double click issue. Not working properly.

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-ui-tree

Double click in angular tree component is not working, here's the sample of code I'm trying to use. Do I need to write anything else in my code, so that it will work?? Please help me on this one. Thank you.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode, TreeModel, TREE_ACTIONS, KEYS, IActionMapping, ITreeOptions } from 'angular-tree-component';

const actionMapping:IActionMapping = {
  mouse: {
    contextMenu: (tree, node, $event) => {
      $event.preventDefault();
      alert(`context menu for ${node.data.name}`);
    },
    dblClick: (tree, node, $event) => {
      if (node.hasChildren) {
        TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_EXPANDED(tree, node, $event);
      }
    },
    click: (tree, node, $event) => {
      $event.shiftKey
        ? TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_ACTIVE_MULTI(tree, node, $event)
        : TREE_ACTIONS.TOGGLE_ACTIVE(tree, node, $event);
    }
  },
  keys: {
    [KEYS.ENTER]: (tree, node, $event) => alert(`This is ${node.data.name}`)
  }
};
```

Comment: **I have resolved this problem by firing an event on expand click and used nodeId to expand the respected respective node.** 
  
  public clickOnExpandCurrentNode($event: Event, tree, node): void { // HTML click function
    const getCurrentNode = tree.treeModel.getNodeById(node.id);
    // Log to the node to see if it exists
    if (getCurrentNode.isExpanded) {
      getCurrentNode.collapse();
    } else {
      getCurrentNode.expand();
    }
  }